# Intellij Code completion in (s)css annoying

Tags: intellij-idea, code-completion

I am developing in IntelliJ IDEA mainly scss and js. When I want to type

```
th, td {
  some style
}
```

Intellij autocompletes td to "text-decoration:;" (and th to text-height) which is highly annoying. I have checked all my settings and plugins and am currently lost. I have the setting "Code Completion > Insert selected suggestion" turned off under "Show suggestions as you type".
My enabled custom plugins are Emmet Everywhere, Save Actions and Vue.js. Disabling those does not solve anything.

I would honestly love to enable autocompletion per language/per extension and not as a global setting.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can't reproduce - Emmet abbreviations are not expanded for me when entering selector names. Anyway, it seems that you have configured Emmet to work on `Space`. What are the **Settings | Editor | Emmet, Expand abbreviation with** and **Settings | Editor | Live Templates, By default expand with** options values?

Comment: @lena I have disabled CSS Emmet and Expand abbreviation is set on Tab. Live templates By default expand with was space and that was the issue! I do not remember setting it explicility but did import a settings file from my co-worker, perhaps that was part of it. Thank you so much for pointing in this direction!

Answer (score 0):

As @lena pointed out, Settings > Live templates > By default expand with was set on space which caused this behaviour. With so many options it can sometimes be hard to find unusual settings.